# KEYCODE_DEL as per deletion of text charactars in text view

Tags: android, textview

I want while three charactors remains in textview KEYCODE_DEL have to occur thanks in advance
in main Activity:

```
     text = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.textbox);
     *********************************************************
     @Override
     public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode,KeyEvent event) {

      if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
           && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {

           //some code

           return true;

       }
       return super.onKeyUp(keyCode,event);
   }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally its working with textwatcher

```
        text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            if(cs.toString().length() == 0)
                text.setText(" ");

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below code if your requirement is to delete each character**

```
ediTextView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
     @Override
     public boolean onKey (View v,int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        return backPressAction(keyCode);
       }
    });

    private boolean backPressAction(int keyCode) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            int keyPressedPosition = mPasswordView.getSelectionStart();
            if (keyPressedPosition > 3) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It's working with password field but not working with usename..what to do